# Converting void* to vector<int>

Tags: c++

I have a function named deserialize which takes as an input:

```
int(*cmp)(void*,void*)
```

So, any function of that type can be taken as a parameter by the function.

For example, if I have a Point structure like this:

```
typedef struct{
    int x, y;
}Point;
```

Now, for this my cmp function is like this:

```
int point_cmp(void* _p1, void* _p2){
    Point* p1=(Point*)_p1;
    Point* p2=(Point*)_p2;
    return (!((p1->x==p2->x) && (p1->y==p2->y)));
}
```

This works.

But I want to do this for a vector.

I want to write a vector_cmp function which can be passed like point_cmp to deserialize.
So, I have tried some thing like this for it, but its wrong:

```
int vector_int_cmp(void* _v1, void* _v2){
    vector<int> *v1 = vector<int> *_v1;
    vector<int> *v2 = vector<int> *_v2;
    auto diff = 0;
    auto v1_it = v1->begin();
    auto v2_it = v2->begin();
    while(v1_it != v1->end() && v2_int != v2->end()){
        if(*v1_it != *v2_it) diff++;
        v1_it++;
        v2_it++;
   } 
   if(0 == diff && (v1_it != v1->end() || v2_it != v2->end())) diff = 1;
   return diff;
}
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Can you explain exactly what is wrong? What problems occur?

Comment: This is C++. You don't have to play those `void*` games.

Comment: You seem to be missing some parentheses in your casting in the `vector_int_cmp` function.

Comment: If you want a vector of `int`s from a pointer that points to the first element of an array of `int`s, then do `int *ptr = static_cast<int *>(voidPtr); vector<int> v(ptr, ptr + size);`

Comment: Also, you *do* know that there [comparison operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_cmp) already defined for `std::vector`?

Comment: I think comparison functions are typically expected to return `-1`, `0` or `+1` if they return integers. In your case you would never return `-1` - is that desired?

Comment: @m01 As far as I know, in C++, the convention is to return `true` if `LHS < RHS`, and `false` otherwise. What you are talking about is the C idiom.

Comment: In my case it must returns following C idioms.

Comment: I have to pass this vector_int_cmp to the deserialize function. Until and unless I cast it to vector<int>, I don't think I can use comparison operators.

Comment: Are the parameters passed to your comparison function pointers to actual `std::vector` instances? Or are they pointers to integers (i.e. an old C-style array)?

Comment: Its an actual std::vector.

Comment: @H2CO3, if the function was expected to return `true` or `false`, I'd expect it to return a value that has the type `bool` :)

Comment: @m01 And indeed, `operator <` returns `bool`. What's the problem?

Comment: @H2CO3 there is no problem. My point was that if you return `true` or `false`, it would make sense to return a `bool`, rather than an `int` (the latter appears to be required here). Thanks for pointing out how to do it the C++ way though, I think that was a useful comment.

Comment: @m01 You are welcome. I missed that returning int was a **requirement.** (It's a stupid requirement anyway...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose that you're doing this to meet some sort of external
interface (which will call back into your function); in pure
C++, there should never be a need for this.  Anyhow:

```
int
vector_compare( void const* p1, void const* p2 )
{
    std::vector<int> const* v1 = static_cast<std::vector<int> const*>( p1 );
    std::vector<int> const* v2 = static_cast<std::vector<int> const*>( p2 );
    return *v1 < *v2
        ? -1
        : *v2 < *v1
        ? 1
        : 0;
}
```

should be all that's necessary.

Answer (score 3):

The immediate problem is that you are casting it wrong. The casts, if C-style, should be like:

```
vector<int> *v1 = (vector<int> *) (_v1);
vector<int> *v2 = (vector<int> *) (_v2);
```

Then the program compiles and works (once you also change `v2_int` to `v2_it` in the loop, that's a typo).

The larger problem is that you should not do things like that in C++. `void *` magic is generally for C, not C++. In C++, you can use tools like templates for writing generic code, and you should rely on standard implementations for comparison operations where possible. Unsurprisingly, `std::vector` has them - although of course doing your own is a good exercise.